# Using mySQL to connect to ODBC database

Tags: mysql, odbc

I see a lot of references to connecting *to* a mySQL database using ODBC. But I want to do it the other way: set up linked tables *in* a mySQL database that are connected *to* a different database (actually Intersystems Cache') via ODBC. How do I do that?

Comment: afaik mysql doesn't have linked tables.  I think I've seen third party (non-free) products that will replicate into a mysql database, maybe look into that.

Comment: No linked tables? I heard that at least there was something called FEDERATED?

Comment: MySQL's federated storage engine _only_ connects to another MySQL instance. It uses the MySQL protocol, not an ODBC connector. You can read about it here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/federated-storage-engine.html

Comment: I voted to mark this question as a duplicate. The linked question is about connecting MySQL to Microsoft SQL Server using federated, but the same applies to any other brand of RDBMS.